# Put boundaries to a movable object in unity

Tags: mouseevent, unity-game-engine

I have draggable (or movable) objects. I want them to stop at certain boundaries in Unity.

I let the user drag the objects using this script:

```
public bool Enabled = false;

void OnMouseDrag()
{
    if(Enabled)
        transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 61.5f));
}
```

I have a quad with an image as a background map. The image has transparency. I want the user to be able to drag the object over the non-transparent part of the map only.

[image: example]

The screenshot shows a sphere and a quad with a map with transparent edges.

I think the current configuration wouldn't enable me to do what I need. How should I modify things? *The script? The map? The draggable object?*

Comment: Could try adding edge/polygoncollider (with shape of that texture) and then move the sphere with physics..(so it would collide to the edges).. or shoot many raycasts at circle edge (and check if pixel color is not transparent..)

Comment: How are you enabling `Enable`? What's the mesh collider's shape?

Comment: @mgear first idea is nice, the second won't do because I think I'll add a background later

Comment: @SP. it's a public variable. I store the reference to the script component (or I use things like `GetComponent<T>()`) and modify it with an `=`. I stated that the collider's a sphere collider

Comment: I meant mesh collider's shape of background? I see you selected background and inspector shows a mesh collider in it. How are you changing Enable?

Comment: @SP. oh you mean that of the quad! sry. it's like a square. I just created a `3D Object > quad` and added the material of the map to it. ...about `Enable` here's an example: `GameObject xInstance = Instantiate(xPrefab) as GameObject;` `xInstance.GetComponent<Movable>().Enabled = true;` where `xPrefab` is a public variable that I set via the inspector _...tell me if the code's not clear_

Comment: @mgear I'm a bit stuck at how to use physics to move my sphere. could you help me with that plz